# Explain structure of Eclipse-Maven Web project in Spring using Kepler

Tags: spring, maven, structure

I am using Kepler to build a Eclipse-Maven project in eclispe. While making the project I am skipping archetype selection on first wizard. then I am selecting packaging as "war".
Eclipse provides me a basic structure after above steps. However, as this is my first Spring/Maven application, I am unable to completely understand the structure.

My Main issue is where to keep my web.xml. No WEB-INF folder is provided, while a META-INF folder is provided.

Also where to keep the basic Dispatcher-Servlet for project and others like root-context, servlet-context etc..

Do I need to create these folders by myself. If yes, Where please? As I am creating a RESTful service, I won't have any views but I guess web.xml is still a must. Currently I am unable to upload an image(nothing happens when I try uploading), will try again soon.

Answer (score 0):

> While making the project I am skipping archetype selection on first
>   wizard. then I am selecting packaging as "war".

You need to select the maven archetype as: maven-archetype-webapp to get the WEB-INF folder & web.xml

[image]

[Check this out](http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-dynamic-web-project-using-maven-in-eclipse/)